# What has been the largest class suit action in the USA by payout?

Tags: united-states, class-action

What has been the largest payout in a class suit action against a corporation in the USA due to deliberate corporate malfeasance of whatever kind?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=largest+class+action+lawsuit+US

Answer (score 3):

At $206 billion, the largest ever was the [Tobacco Master Settlement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobacco_Master_Settlement_Agreement) in 1998.